# How to know/ find best websites based on the web technology

Tags: html, css

I'm preparing for interviews..I wanna do some research before going to one..When I was reading, there were questions like "what's your favorite website? and why?" I guess answer they would expecting be based on the technology used rather than just look and feel..(correct me if I'm wrong). If based on technology..how to find them..There were trillion and trillion of pages online and its hard to go and look its source code..Any insight??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some websites and apps with great technology behind them out there, but it is also possible that they are more interested in why you like the website than what it is.

with some of the best websites, (Stack Overflow included), its not about what the website is built with, but what it enables you to do.

taking Stack Overflow as an example, people helping each other through programming problems has been possible with newsgroups since the birth of the internet, but what makes it different, is the reward system, ease of use, and being able to filter it by how it is tagged.

Answer (score 1):

I usually find the most influential people in a field/technology and look at what websites they read. This helps me to find quality websites related to the field/technology I am interested in.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an iPhone, i strongly suggest you get techDygest.

They do a great job, for example, putting 10 articles about the iPad2 into one clean, crisp article.

*EDIT*
Just got some media coverage on them: http://venturebeat.com/2011/03/24/techdygest-iphone/